# Autodesk Forge : set fullscreen mode

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to set the viewer in fullscreen mode (like the button in the default toolbar) with the API : Autodesk.Viewing.ScreenModeDelegate.
On the documentation, it is written that I have to use the methods:
- doScreenModeChange(oldMode,newMode)
- getMode()

It is also written that I have to override theses methods. I am new with Forge and Node.js. Do I have to override theses methods on server side or client side ?

Does someone have an example on how we can override theses methods ?

Thanks

Comment: checking viewer3d.js, I found it can be simply toggled by viewer.nextScreenMode(), if it is normal view, this call will set full screen. if it is full screen, this call will set it back to normal.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't find the method "nextScreenMode" on the viewer. I have checked on the online documentation (https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/), the same, I don't find it. Maybe it's a version problem... I use this version for my tests : https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client

Comment: The `nextScreenMode` method is inherited from `ScreenModeMixin` by the `Viewer3D`, that is not list on documentation, but you can see this line `av.ScreenModeMixin.prototype.apply( Viewer3D.prototype );` in the `viewer3D.js`. It has introduced from the Viewer v1.x with my experience.

Comment: The `forge-api-nodejs-client` is a Forge backend SDK, it doesn't contain the Forge Viewer. The viewer version can be found from your webpage (the view of your nodejs app such as html, ejs, etc.) where you host the viewer app (frontend) via HTML `<script src="..."></script>` tag or checking the global variable `LMV_VIEWER_VERSION` in your Web Browser console.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working !! I don't find where I can validate the answer (set the green arrow to tell it's ok).